# ExtJS qtip and messagebox issues, text is truncated/missing depending on the browser

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I am using EXTJS 4 (4.2.1.883) and experiencing issues with qtips and message boxes, on different browsers (Chrome, IE and Firefox) the text is getting truncated at different lengths.

1. qtips on textfields getting truncated at different lengths on different browsers, here is what I have set for one textfield, in firefox I would get 'New U'

   msgTarget: 'side',
   maxLength: 15 ,
   enforceMaxLength: true,
   blankText: 'New UserName is required '
2. Ext.Msg.show, the msg is getting truncated, different browsers are truncating text at different lengths, in some cases I can only see one or two lines of the msg and the remainder is not visible.

   ```
       Ext.MessageBox.show({
           title: 'There is an issue here', 
           msg:statusErrorMsg,
           buttons: Ext.MessageBox.OK
       });
   ```

Firefox seems to be the most badly behaved, followed by IE and then chrome.

My understanding was that EXTJS would handle such formatting issues but it is not behaving as expected, any ideas here on what am I doing wrong?

Thank You.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle to show us the issue?

Comment: Hi Karlipoppins,  thanks for responding and excellent point, I should have included a fiddle.  Issue resolved by changing the message box to be Ext.Msg.show  ,  the qtip is a bug in extjs 4.2 that has not been fixed despite a few threads at Sencha claiming it is fixed,  fix was to replace all the spaces with &nbsp;  for example,  blankText: 'Hello&nbsp;World'.   Now I need to close this ticket, need to figure out how.

Comment: Glad to see you figured out your own problem. Just wait a bit and you'll be able to accept your own answer. Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue resolved by changing the message box to be Ext.Msg.show , the qtip issue is a bug in extjs 4.2 that has not been fixed (despite a few threads at Sencha claiming it is fixed), fix I made was to replace all the spaces, for example

```
blankText: 'New&nbsp;UserName&nbsp;is&nbsp;required'
```